# What is the purpose of .loc in pandas data frame

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe

I am basically migrating from R to Python. I wanted to subset my data frame based on a column. While going through stack-overflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas), I found a solution.

But consider the below code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': 'foo bar foo bar foo bar foo foo'.split(),
                   'B': 'one one two three two two one three'.split(),
                   'C': np.arange(8), 'D': np.arange(8) * 2})

df1 = df[df['A'] == "foo"]
df1
df2 = df.loc[df['A'] == "foo"]
df2
```

Both df1 and df2 are same.

So my question is : what is the requirement for `loc` function in the first place. Please bear in mind, that I come from R background and in R, we dont have to use `loc` type function for subsetting data-frame.

Comment: Please read [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing) and [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) if you have further questions then edit your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am learning pandas myself, so excuse the answer that isnt particular in depth. The .loc is has a 'location' function allowing you to note a place in the dataframe DF[1,3] in R. Or allowing you to put in two grid coordinates, where otherwise you could have only 1 parameter.

Now I could be wrong, as its been a while since I've had a look at pandas, and as I mentioned I am also only learning it.

It is listed as an indexing function on the website
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html

Answer (score 1):

The loc method gives direct access to the dataframe allowing for assignment to specific locations of the dataframe. This is in contrast to the ix method or bracket notation that produces a copy of the requested portion of the dataframe. The consequence is that you cannot make assignments to the dataframe via these methods. The iloc method shares the same characteristic as loc.